# Como le hago para devolver el valor de los minutos con símbolo negativo o positivo - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Este es el método que uso:

```
      $valor = $horaactual->diffInMinutes($fechaVigencia);
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente agrega a la función `diffInMinutes` el siguiente parámetro como `false`.

```
$today = Carbon::now();
$yesterday = Carbon::now()->subDays(1);
dump("today - yesterday diff", $today->diffInMinutes($yesterday, false));
dump("yesterday - today diff", $yesterday->diffInMinutes($today, false));
```

La declaración del método se ve así:

```
/**
     * Get the difference in minutes rounded down.
     *
     * @param \Carbon\CarbonInterface|\DateTimeInterface|string|null $date
     * @param bool                                                   $absolute Get the absolute of the difference
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function diffInMinutes($date = null, $absolute = true)
    {
        return (int) ($this->diffInSeconds($date, $absolute) / static::SECONDS_PER_MINUTE);
    }
```

Salida:

```
"today - yesterday diff"
-1439
"yesterday - today diff"
1439
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! por tu ayuda